# Tab in Chunk using itextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I´m trying to create tabs in chunks.

Using the example DirectorOverview3 in [Chapter 02](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=45)  I know I can do it using this:

```
Chunk tab1 = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark(), 200, true);
```

The problem is that it says it is obsolete. How should it be done now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The new way to accomplish this is to set the "TabSettings" property on the paragraph and then add a Chunk.TABBING to the paragraph.

So instead of:

```
paragrpah.Add(new Chunk(tab1));
```

Use:

```
paragraph.TabSettings = new TabSettings(200); //Instead of the code in your question
paragraph.Add(Chunk.TABBING);
```

I hope this helps others working through the book.